# Iterating over a list while updating a dictionary with Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For example, I have a list that has copies of certain items:

```
list = [item1,item2,item2,item3,item4,item4]
```

And I want to iterate over `list` and put each item in an empty dictionary `dict = {}`

`for item in list:
     # if the item isn't in the dict, add it and set value to 1
     # if item is already in dict, increment value by one`

What is the best way to manipulate the dictionary and using the `for` loop variable `item`?

Comment: or using a plain dict: `for item in my_list: some_dict[item] = some_dict.get(item, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
diction = defaultdict(lambda:0, {})
for item in your_list:
    diction[item] += 1
```

All your keys will be initialized to 1 if they are not in the dict already or incremented otherwise.

Comment: just realized that and edited.

Comment: still, should probably just use `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helps!